# Change frame caption forecolor

Tags: vb6, colors, frame, caption

I have a radio button within a frame (frame1).  On frame 2, I have a number of checkboxes.  This frame (frame2) becomes editable when the radio button is selected from frame1.  How can I modify my code so the Caption of frame2's forecolor changes also?

I've tried adding the following to the logic already in place for enabling the frame, but doesn't work.

```
frame2.ForeColor = vbRed (should work?)
frame2.Caption = vbRed
```

I've also tried the Hex color code with no look.
Can anyone advise?

Im using a enum to assign the radio buttons.

(Found in global declaration)
    Private Enum
    ExampleRef optB1_blah = 1
    etc... 
    optB5_blah = 4 
    End Enum

(This code is found in a function)

```
If Example(ExampleRef.optB5_radiobtnchoice).Value Then
'//bug fix -
frame2.ForeColor = vbRed
  '//If Not statement with unrelated logic

    If vblnShowErrors Then
      Err.Raise 10000, VALIDATION, "error, you cant make this choice."
    End If

    blnDataFail = True
  End If
End If

blnMinData = Not blnDataFail
End If
```

Comment: frame2.ForeColor = vbRed *should* work, I just tested it out right now.

Comment: Also, what event are you using for the radio button? Click? GotFocus? Something else?

Comment: If optExample(ExampleRef.optB5_radiobtn5).Value '//Then carry out some logic

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I've added to my question.

Comment: That doesn't tell me when the code is called.  Is it called in a function, a subroutine, an event, what?  Post your code.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables added code example

Comment: Poor practice anyway.  The whole thing assumes that users are using default system colors that let "red" text even be visible. See Raymond Chen's remarks http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/12/6648399.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this, I was looking in the wrong function, long day!  The frame.ForeColor = X syntax was fine.